# JsFl and listbox

Tags: flash-cs4, xul, jsfl

I'm using JsFl in my Flash CS4 application to provide some feedback to our 2D artists.
I'd like to display a dialog box, thanks to JsFl, filled with a listbox or a tree...
And my problem is : my dialog box is displayed but my listbox is freaking empty (even listheaders are missing).

here is my JsFl call to my XML:
`var result = fl.getDocumentDOM().xmlPanel(fl.configURI + "Commands/dialogbox.xml");`

and here is my XML file:

`<?xml version='1.0'?>
<dialog name='dialog' title='dialogbox' buttons='accept,cancel' width='300' height='400'>
<box>
<listbox>
        <listhead>
            <listheader label="Name"></listheader>
            <listheader label="Age"></listheader>
            <listheader label="City"></listheader>
        </listhead>
        <listcols>
            <listcol flex="1"></listcol>
            <listcol flex="1"></listcol>
            <listcol flex="1"></listcol>
        </listcols>
        <listitem>
            <listcell label="Julia"></listcell>
            <listcell label="19"></listcell>
            <listcell label="Boston"></listcell>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <listcell label="Sandra"></listcell>
            <listcell label="25"></listcell>
            <listcell label="London"></listcell>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <listcell label="Sharon"></listcell>
            <listcell label="35"></listcell>
            <listcell label="Paris"></listcell>
        </listitem>
    </listbox>
</box>

</dialog>`

Any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not using the proper vocabulary for a JSFL panel. Check out [Extending Flash book](http://amzn.to/dG53on). It's the only full XMLPanel reference that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can download sample files of [Extending Flash MX 2004 book from here](http://www.apress.com/9781590593042/). You will find Dialog Designer extension for Flash IDE. You can use that visual builder to build your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Flash only uses a subset of XUL as mentioned in the docs here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fea.html

Finding what is supported is not as easy, I found this pdf here that lists the supported subset:
http://w3.id.tue.nl/fileadmin/id/objects/E-Atelier/Phidgets/Software/Flash/fl8_using_flash.pdf